# Load existing .wsdl file into Web project with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, web-applications, wsdl, build.gradle

I’m developing an web app in java & gradle and i use a .wsdl file to get certain values from web service. My problem is that i don't know how to load .wsdl file dynamic and also to be included in the .war file.

I've managed to load the .wsdl file from static source with file: code in eclipse but when i move the project on the server which automatically generates the .war file the .wsdl file is not loaded/included.

Can someone tell me how to set up dynamic classpath or another solution to load/include the .wsdl file into project and in the .war file?

Comment: Create a resources directory: src/main/resources

Comment: I have created the resources directory and included the .wsdl file but i don't know how to load dynamic the file.